# Does a proper Gamist-Narrativist hybrid system exist?

Tags: rpg-theory

I was thinking on some game design issues, and I realized that I had never actually run across a proper Gamist-Narrativist system designed to equally support both kinds of play.  I looked at [this](http://www.indie-rpgs.com/archive/index.php?topic=5761.0) discussion at The Forge, where it's suggested that it is possible, but all the example games have one dominant form.  To be clear, I'm not looking for Gamist with Narrativist trappings (like 13th age and its One Unique Thing mechanic), and I'm not looking for primarily Narrativist with Gamist trappings.  My question is this: **Does a true 1 to 1 Gamist-Narrativist Hybrid system exist?**

I considered making this question what would define a true hybrid system, but that seems like a discussion question; this seems like a more solid way of getting a handle on what a system like that would look like.  This question refers to [GNS Theory](http://www.indie-rpgs.com/articles/3/) again, so I'd like answers to be based on that.

To clear up confusion, I'm not asking for some pristine, perfectly mathematically balance between "Gamist mechanics" and "Narrativist mechanics".  That's impossible and absurd.  What I am asking for is a game where the main draws are both Gamist and Narrativist in nature.  As a helping example, The Riddle of Steel was lauded as a 1:1 Narrativist-Simulationist system. On the surface (like me), you might originally have assumed that it was nearly pure simulationist, but the game attracts easily based on both its detailed combat mechanics (Simulationist) and its spiritual attributes (Narrativist).  The game wouldn't be the hybrid it is without both of these things.  A proper Gamist-Narrativist hybrid would include both a primary gamist mechanical draw and a primary narrativist mechanical draw.

Comment: No arguing over GNS in comments. Take the GNS link in his question as given for the scope of this question.

Comment: @shatterspike1 It would be helpful if you updated your question with the exact definitions you mean. [GNS Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNS_Theory) was an evolving and amorphous body of work with many interpretations, and as Edwards abandoned the theory around 2005, I don’t know whether people can successfully infer what you regard as canonical.

Comment: @shatterspike1 It would also be helpful if you talked about which major systems in this vein you have considered and rejected. For example, Fate is a well-known example of a system deliberately designed to align narrative and game, so it would be helpful to know whether it fits the definitions you’re using and why.

Comment: I'm a little confused about all these downvotes.  I've laid out the definition of what I want in the link above in what I think is fairly clear way, including the definitions of Gamist and Narrativist included in the link.  Would anyone like to say why they're downvoting?

Comment: Perhaps people are objecting to the use of GNS Theory to classify game designs? The definition you posted states that doing so is one of the major “misunderstandings of GNS” – which was mentioned in [the answers to your previous question on this topic](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/21815/8012).

Comment: That is true, but there's also the idea of using a drill to drive in a screw rather than a hammer.  You can probably use either, but one tool is much better suited for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Hollowpoint

Questions based on GNS theory are hard to answer because GNS theory itself is so ill-defined, but your link does contain this in its definition of gamism:

> it includes victory and loss conditions for characters

I know of only one RPG that includes a real victory condition, and that's Hollowpoint. In Hollowpoint, you can win the game by having your character retire from the game as a direct result of his Complication. If you win, you get pats on the back, maybe a free drink, and you make a new character that joins the game in the next scene.

I suspect the rest of Hollowpoint is strongly Narrativist, though I'm not entirely sure. The dice mechanic is fairly abstract, somewhat reminiscent of *Dogs in the Vineyard* (though very different). Play is driven primarily through the fiction, but revolves entirely around conflict (players vs opposition, never player vs player), which is resolved with that dice mechanic. The stat you use is not about how you do it, but about what you accomplish with it: do you **Kill** someone, **Terror**ize someone, **Dig** for information, **Take** something, **Con** someone, or do something **Cool**?

Standard Hollowpoint is extremely violent, and involves hypercompetent James Bond, Jason Bourne, MIB-style agents or criminals doing whatever it takes in order to accomplish their goal. But conflict doesn't necessarily have to be violent; basically any attempt to overcome an obstacle can be considered a conflict. Though only one person picking a lock is kinda boring; it works better if you take the scene a lot broader where one guy might be picking a lock to **take** something, while others lay waste to the guards, dig for info or do other cool stuff.

Characters can't die against the will of the player, but at some point your character will be so vulnerable that you will choose to let him die or otherwise leave the game. "Move on", I think it's called. Another reason to "move on" is of course to win. Whether you die, retire, flee or join the enemy is irrelevant for the mechanics, but of course extremely important to the story. You could win by dying in an appropriate way (sacrificing your life to save the bad guy that's secretly your son, for example).

The system is very simple, and there's not even a hint of simulationism.

Answer (score 5):

## It’s not only possible, but surprisingly old-school

Ron Edwards discusses Game/Narrative hybrids extensively [in the linked forum discussion](http://indie-rpgs.com/archive/index.php?topic=5761.msg58413#msg58413). He shows how Game and Narrative are not opposed but merely *different,* a recurring theme in GNS Theory. He speculates that most perceived conflicts between Game and Narrative occur only when players add heavy Simulation into the mix, which over-constrains the game. Edwards proposes that Game/Narrative hybrids should actually be easy to create, “simply by altering the reward system to reflect the . . . Social Contract” and offers several examples of very old-school games that support this style of play (emphasis added).

> **Toon, Tunnels & Trolls,** and even **Paranoia** all offer good instances, I think. Comedic, strategic action converts to savage, biting satire very easily. **Elfs** is written in this tradition. This is a cool thing when it happens.

## *Paranoia* and friends

Having played *Paranoia,* I’m personally familiar with the way it encourages both Game and Narrative play. To succeed, *Paranoia* players must:

- survive and outwit the GM and the other players to come out on top
- in the most madcap, macabre, surprising, and stylish ways possible.

You can play it as a game to win or a story to tell, but it really works out best when you do both. *Paranoia* is a perfect example of why [GNS Theory is not “a means to classify game design”](http://www.indie-rpgs.com/articles/3/) but rather a description of how people actually play games. The Game and Narrative elements aren’t in the rules or the mechanical design, but are instead a product of the whole *Paranoia* system and play environment: the setting, the advice to GMs, the props, the way people actually play.

In particular, *Paranoia* is a perfect example of altering the reward system to [gamify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamification) the desired outcome: a cut-throat, competitive, zany role-playing game. You don’t win in *Paranoia* by building an optimal character for the setting and then lining up the right attack and damage bonuses; in fact, doing so is grounds for the GM to summarily kill your PC. Instead, you win by coming up with absurd plans that convince the lying, cheating GM to cheat in your favor, and convince the other players to let him. This makes it more of a diplomacy game than a dice game, but that’s still Game.

In recent years, games like ***Fiasco*** and ***Apocalypse World*** have refined many of these ideas. Both of them do away with the lying, cheating GM – *Apocalypse World* gives the GM very strict rules to follow, and *Fiasco* does away with the job entirely. They codify the narrative reward system by turning the traditional “how to GM” advice into rules of the game. Depending on your players, *Fiasco*’s Game elements may become vestigial (like keeping score in Cards Against Humanity), but I have actually seen players game the reward system. In any case, this whole “set the players up to compete and fail in an untenable, comedic/dramatic situation” genre looks like fertile ground for Game/Narrative hybrid play.

## *Fate* and the fate point economy

Some games really run with the idea of structuring their reward systems around a narrative, and vice versa. *Fate* is a prime example, with narrative concerns driving game tactics, which then feed the game resource economy, which then drives narrative pacing. I suspect that *Fate* actually exceeds Ron Edwards’ expectations for Game/Narrative play, as most of his writing seems to assume that one of the modes must ultimately take a back seat to the other, to be [“the point”](http://indie-rpgs.com/archive/index.php?topic=5761.msg58308#msg58308) of play. But in games like *Fate,* the Game and Narrative elements are not only harmonized, but actually interdependent in play.